# Why we use Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord

Tags: gtkmm, gtkmm3

I just started learning gtkmm3.
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-range-example.html.en

In above example TreeModel is used without explaining about it .

Can anyone explain scenarios where `Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the range example the Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecords is used for the Gtk::ComboBox widget to describe what types of data is stored.

When you get to the sections on the [`Gtk::Treeview` widget tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-treeview.html.en) and the [`Gtk::ComboBox` tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-combobox.html.en) the use of `Gtk::TreeModel` is explained further. Think of it as describing which data types are stored and their access names are defined.